# How to replace invalid characters using java

Tags: java, xml, regex

Invalid XML: Error on line 190: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x10) was found in the CDATA section.

I get this error while parsing an XML file, I used String.replaceAll to replace this character but my regex pattern seems to be incorrect.

The following is a different string, but it just gives me back the original string. How should I do it?

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\^p", "");
```

Comment: How are you parsing it? CDATA sections are unparsed character data, There is no such thing as an invalid character, because it is not supposed to be parsed, and replacing or modifying it is almost certainly a bad idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
String replaced = your_original_string.replaceAll("\\x10", "");
```

1. The `xdd...` is the Java syntax to match a single unicode character
2. Your error said `Unicode: 0x10`

Answer (score 1):

```
str = str.replace("\u0010", "");
```

Or maybe you need a space

```
str = str.replace("\u0010", " ");
```